# How to run Django and Php on one Apache2?

Tags: php, python, django, apache

I want to run my Django app and mediawiki at same domain on one Apache2.But I find there is a problem hard to solve.

In my config, localhost and localhost/mediawiki can normal access, but when I access to localhost/dblog(It's my Django app's directory), browser shows "Bad Request (400)".

I trid to google and another related questions at stackoverflow, but still can't solve this problem.

Here is my Apache2 config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName localhost

    <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www>
            Options ALl
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess dblog python-path=/var/www/dblog:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup dblog
    WSGIScriptAlias  /dblog /var/www/dblog/dblog/wsgi.py


    <Directory /var/www/dblog>
            Options +ExecCGI
            <Files wsgi.py>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is more about server administration than about programming, probably off-topic for this site. You may get luckier at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: Thank you! I have solved the problem. My apache config is right, but my django app setting has some problem. I have to read django doc carefully.